# How can I catch a jQuery change event when I am manually changing the input value through another jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well I am facing a problem to handle the change event of a `input` field. Because I am changing the text of the input field by another script. Consequently I am not able to catch the event.

[image]

Look, here I have 2 buttons `-` and `+` when I will click either -/+ then the some value is inserting inside the text box. It's a numeric value and I have manually added increment and decrements by including and reducing 1. Anyway, as my text inside the text box is changing however, I am not able to capture the event in `jQuery`
My code is as below

```
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>-</button><input type="text" id="abc" /><button>+</button>
```

and none of my jQuery function is capture the event.

```
$("#abc").change(function(){
    alert();
});
$("#abc").click(function(){
    alert();
});
```

Because I have added the text through another `jQuery` helper. So how can I catch the text change event. I don't want to write down the code inside increment and decrements function. I want to keep that code intact. So is there any way I can solve this easily? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
Here is the update code for increment and decrements

```
var btn = $(this),
            oldValue = $('#abc').val().trim(),
            newVal = 0;

        if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
            newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
        } else {
            newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
        }
$('#abc').val(newVal);
```

Comment: can youp lease share the other script

Comment: Tip of the day: get into using Vue.js if you have data that needs to synchronize on multiple places. It is combine-able with jQuery. Also, you're using the change event, which is for selects, use input instead. $('#some_text_box').on('input', function() {})

Comment: Adding a framework (like vue) will be too much overhead in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`.trigger(event)`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the event, events are triggered when user interacts with element.

```js
$("#abc").change(function() {
  console.log('changed', this.value);
});

$("button").click(function() {
  var btn = $(this),
    oldValue = $('#abc').val().trim(),
    newVal = 0;

  if (oldValue != '') {
    if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
      newVal = parseInt(oldValue, 10) + 1;
    } else {
      newVal = parseInt(oldValue, 10) - 1;
    }
  }
  
  $('#abc').val(newVal).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-dir="down">-</button><input type="text" id="abc" /><button data-dir="up">+</button>
```

Comment: Your solution is working, but partially. Because when the input field is totally empty then if I try to push on plus or minus button then it is not working. but on load wen it is coming with a value then it's working fine.

Comment: @lazycoder, Can you share the plus or minus button code? It would be better to have a look at complete picture

Comment: Sure!! why not. Let me provide a snapshot.

Comment: `var btn = $(this),
            oldValue = $('#abc').val().trim(),
            newVal = 0;

        if (btn.attr('data-dir') == 'up') {
            newVal = parseInt(oldValue) + 1;
        } else {
            newVal = parseInt(oldValue) - 1;
        }
$('#abc').val(newVal);`

Comment: @lazycoder, You need to handle that condition(empty text) in your code, I have updated the snippet

Comment: Yeah, seems so. I have already tried. It's working now. But I need time to test for all. Is there any problem due to this modification. And there is no other feasible way I can see. However I wanted to keep the increment and decrements function intact. But there is no way may be.

Comment: @lazycoder, You can set initial value as 0 and I would also suggest to use type as "number", i.e. `<input type="number" id="abc"  value="0"/>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142688/discussion-between-lazycoder-and-satpal).

Answer (score 1):

Since the other script that is changing the input is also using jquery, the most reliable way is probably just triggering a change event manually after the input value has been updated.

```
$('.counter').val(oldValue + 1).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Sorry! I want to keep that function intact. As I have mentioned in my question. Because this function is used in multiple places. But this feature is need only 2 of them.

Comment: You write that you don't want the increment functionality in the other function. This is just making sure a lifecycle event is called. It's independent from whether or not you handle that event.